# How to tell if an Excel Workbook is protected

Tags: excel, password-protection, worksheet, vba

I can use properties of an Excel Worksheet to tell if the worksheet is protected (Worksheet.Protection, Worksheet.ProtectContents etc).

How can I tell using VBA if the entire workbook has been protected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

I need the `Workbook.ProtectStructure` and `Workbook.ProtectWindows` properties.

Answer (score 2):

Worksheet.ProtectedContents is what you would need to use, on each Worksheet.

So I would set up a loop like this:

```
Public Function wbAllSheetsProtected(wbTarget As Workbook) As Boolean 

Dim ws As Worksheet 

wbAllSheetsProtected = True

For Each ws In wbTarget.Worksheets 
    If ws.ProtectContents = False Then 
        wbAllProtected = False
        Exit Function 
    End If 
Next ws 

End Function
```

The function will return True if every worksheet is protected, and False if there are any worksheets not protected.  I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I'm looking for.  All worksheets can be protected without the workbook being protected.  I need the workbook to be protected so that the user can't unhide hidden sheets.  I found the answer myself: Workbook.ProtectStructure and Workbook.ProtectWindows.